# How would you set the font color of your back button icon to white or black depending on the color of image behind it?

Tags: css, less

I am using ionic to create a mobile app and on one of the pages, I have my header bar set to transparent and an image is the background.

I have a default back button which is white colored. However, if the image behind it is something like this https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/white-wallpaper-8.jpg then the button won't show.

Here is the mark up in question:

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-clear">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button button-icon ion-arrow-left-c" ng-click="goBack()"></button>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content scroll="true" class="no-header my-view">
    <ion-slide-box class="item-slide-box">      
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="post in vm.post.images" ng-cloak>
            <img class="img-ng" ng-src="{{image}}">                
        </ion-slide>    
    </ion-slide-box>
```

Comment: I see you tagged this as CSS/LESS but this is not going to be a CSS issue, as CSS cannot determine what color an image is.  You will need to do this in your template, and add an appropriate class to the button which changes the font color.

Comment: Maybe try playing around with using CSS blending modes: http://jsfiddle.net/qqd7e172/

Comment: thanks that is pretty interesting.  im trying to learn LESS.  is there a way to have a function where if the background is over a certain RGB threshold, then just use white, otherwise use black?

Comment: No, Less has no image analysis/processing stuff so it can't know the color of your background too.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you could try getting the dominant color of the background image like [this](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/).

Next, based on the color, if the color lies beyond a certain range (defined by you), you can set an appropriate class to the button. The class would specify if the background is white or black. This isn't specifically a LESS solution, but you can modify your LESS theme based on this. Like calling *less.modifyVars()* and reassigning the variables.